# How to authenticate with DefaultAzureCredentials in VS Code with Java?

Tags: java, azure, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to develop an Azure function with Java 11. I am able to authenticate using VisualStudioCodeCredential but when I try to use the DefaultAzureCredential class I get the below error. It is my understanding that for this app to run locally and in the Azure hosted environment that I need the DefaultAzureCredential. Why does this happen and how do I fix it? Is there a better/preferred way to do the authentication?

```
Caused by: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: DefaultAzureCredential 
authentication failed. ---> IntelliJCredential authentication failed. Error Details: 
Unrecognized field "tenantId" (class 
com.azure.identity.implementation.IntelliJAuthMethodDetails), not marked as ignorable (4 known 
properties: "authMethod", "azureEnv", "accountEmail", "credFilePath"])
```

Here is my code. The error occurs when I try to get the secret from the vault.

```
    secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder().vaultUrl(System.getenv("KeyVaultURL"))
            .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()).buildClient();
    String secretValue= secretClient.getSecret("secretValue").getValue();
```

Using VisualStudioCodeCredential works:

```
    secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder().vaultUrl(System.getenv("KeyVaultURL"))
            .credential(new VisualStudioCodeCredential().build()).buildClient();
    String secretValue= secretClient.getSecret("secretValue").getValue();
```

Links to some of the docs that I have used for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity#key-concepts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth#default-azure-credential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was occurring due to how DefaultAzureCredential chooses the authentication method. During runtime an error occurred because the app was unable to authenticate using IntelliJ  authentication even though the app was running from Visual Studio Code.

> [Default Azure credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth#default-azure-credential)
>
> The DefaultAzureCredential is appropriate for most scenarios where the application ultimately runs in the Azure Cloud. DefaultAzureCredential combines credentials that are commonly used to authenticate when deployed, with credentials that are used to authenticate in a development environment. The DefaultAzureCredential will attempt to authenticate via the following mechanisms in order.
>
> [image: DefaultAzureCredential Authentication Order]

Microsoft provides a way to get around this with the [ChainedTokenCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Azure-Identity-Examples#chaining-credentials) class.

> The ChainedTokenCredential class provides the ability to link together multiple credential instances to be tried sequentially when authenticating. The following example demonstrates creating a credential which will attempt to authenticate using managed identity, and fall back to certificate authentication if a managed identity is unavailable in the current environment. This example authenticates an EventHubClient from the azure-eventhubs client library using the ChainedTokenCredential. There's also a compilable sample to create a Key Vault secret client you can copy-paste.

Using the ChainedTokenCredential I was able to change the order to check ManagedIdentityCredential and then VisualStudioCodeCredential.